# Pgfplots 3d Arc Arrow

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, draw

I've got a (parametrised) truncated cylinder using the code below:

```
\documentclass[crop,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis line style = {draw=none},ticks = none]
            \def\h{.2}
            \def\r{1}
            \def\R{2}

            %\def\ang{2}
            %\begin{scope}[rotate around x=pi/2,rotate around z=\ang]
                %\draw[->] (0:0) arc (0:10:1);
            %\end{scope}

            \addplot3 [surf,color=black,faceted color=black,opacity=.1,domain=0:2*pi,y domain=0:1,samples=50,samples y=15] ({((\r-\R)*y+\R)*cos(deg(x))},{((\r-\R)*y+\R)*sin(deg(x))},{y*\h});

        \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I'm looking to add a (parametrised) line on the bottom plane, a line on the cylinder, an arc between the two lines, and a node to label the angle the cylinder makes with the horizontal plane, depicted in red below:

[image]

The parameter is the angle (`\ang` in the code and the blue bit in the picture above) of the plane around the vertical axis in in which to draw this triangular arc thing. Of course the `$\theta$` angle is also a parameter, it should be `atan(\h/(\R-\r))` where in the code I have put `10`, since even that hasn't yet worked for me. Attempts using the commented out code with `\draw[...] ... arc ...` have borne no fruit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to do it. Although if you change the arrow head (to `latex`, for example) it doesn't look aligned because it remains two dimensional.

```
\documentclass[crop,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}%,tikz-3dplot}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[hide axis,axis equal]
    \def\h{2}
    \def\r{1}
    \def\R{2}

    \addplot3 [surf,color=black,faceted color=black,opacity=.1,data cs=polar,domain=0:360,y domain=\r:\R,samples=50,samples y=15,data cs=polar] {(1-(y-\r)/(\R-\r))*\h};

    \def\ang{-100}
    \def\f{.7}
    \def\ff{.3}
    \def\fff{.5}
    \def\ffff{.8}
    \draw[blue,thick] ({\ff*\R*cos(\ang)},{\ff*\R*sin(\ang)},0) -- ({\R*cos(\ang)},{\R*sin(\ang)},0) -- ({\f*\R*cos(\ang)},{\f*\R*sin(\ang)},{(1-(\f*\R-\r)/(\R-\r))*\h});

    \def\fr{.5*\R}
    \addplot3[thick,variable=t,samples y=0,blue,domain=0:{atan(\h/(\R-\r))}
    ,->] ({\R*cos(\ang)+(\fr*cos(t))*cos(\ang-180)},{\R*sin(\ang)+(\fr*cos(t))*sin(\ang-180)},{\fr*sin(t)}) node[xshift=.05cm,yshift=-.55cm]{$\theta$};

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The formula `({(\R-\fr*cos(t))*cos(\ang)},{(\R-\fr*cos(t))*sin(\ang)},{\fr*sin(t)}) `
draws the same curve and is more legible.